# how to print <i> tag with ng-repeat getting the length by {{d.stars.length}}

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

```
<span><i class="fa fa-star colored"></i>
    <i>{{d.stars}}</i>
    </span>
```

I want to print `<i class="fa fa-star colored"></i>` getting the length from "{{d.stars.length}}" and print the `<i>` tag each time there is an increment in the length.

Help me as I am new at angular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you mean this ?

```js
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $compile) {
  $scope.stars = 3;
  $scope.starsArray = [1,2,3];
  $scope.getStars = function(num) {
      return new Array(num);   
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app="myapp">
       <head>
          <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
       </head>

       <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
           <p>If $scope.stars is an int</p>
           <i ng-repeat="star in getStars(stars) track by $index" class="fa fa-star"></i>
           <hr/>
           <p>If $scope.stars is an array</p>
           <i ng-repeat="star in starsArray track by $index" class="fa fa-star"></i>
       </body>
</html>
```

As far as I know ng-repeat only accepts a collection as parameter, so we transform the number into an array, then we just ng-repeat over it.

***edit:***

added array-like ng-repeat

Comment: yes exactly but what if i want to give the length by {{d.stars.length}} so that it can print as much as it requires 
thanks

Comment: @resume then you would just use `ng-repeat='star in d.stars.length...'`

Comment: @resume Is d.stars an array or object ?

Comment: @martijn i have used filters to do that Thanks for helping though :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<span><i class="fa fa-star colored"></i>
    <i>{{d.stars.length}}</i>
    </span>
```

length will automatically update.

Comment: no no i want to get the length and then print stars as much as the length is